# Как программно выключить компьютер?

Tags: c#, windows, winforms

Как программно выключить компьютер?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("cmd", "/c shutdown -s -f -t 00");
```

или без `cmd`

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("shutdown", "/s /t /f 00");
```

Описание примененных ключей:

> ```
> /s         Завершение работы компьютера.
> /t xxx     Задание задержки в xxx секунд перед завершением работы компьютера.
>            Допустимый диапазон: 0-315360000 (10 лет); значение по умолчанию: 30.
>            Если период таймаута больше 0, применяется параметр /f.
> /f         Принудительное закрытие запущенных приложений без предупреждения пользователей.
>            Параметр /f используется, если для параметра /t задано значение больше 0.
> ```

Так же можно воспользоваться и таким [советом](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2921905/wmi-to-reboot-remote-machine)